# How does a webpage send a message to a Safari Web Extension?

Tags: safari, safari-web-extension

How does javascript code on a webpage trigger the sending of a message to a Safari Web Extension?

It appears `browser.runtime.connectNative()` will allow a background script to communicate with the native app. Most specifically, stateful data can be sent over a runtime.Port.

It also appears that `browser.runtime.connect()` will allow a content script to communicate with a background script, however as soon as the content script is present the following (correct) warning is issued to the end user:

[image: This extension can read and alter webpages]

There does not appear to be a documented mechanism for a webpage to send data to a background script. How is this done?

Note: this question refers to Safari Web Extensions announced by Apple for MacOS in 2020, and iOS in 2021.

Answer (score 1):

A webpage does not have access to `browser.runtime.*` methods, so your only bet is to use `window.postMessage()`. [There is something written on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#using_window.postmessage_in_extensions) about using this in extensions, however it doesn't explicitly say if it should work or not.

I just did some tests (on Safari / Monterey), and my background script could not hear a window.postMessage with target `*` from a webpage (without a contentscript, just in the javascript from the page), so that road seems closed.

If you want to communicate to a native app, you could try weird things like register a custom url, or opening a port and websocket-connect to that. I guess in theory you could then have the native app ping the background script and the background script could insert a content-script, which could then communicate, seems a bit convoluted.